# How to Display Records in HTML from Angular having Data in Array Json format ? MVC My code attached

Tags: html, arrays, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am trying to display data i have in json format in array to html but it is not showing any result.

Code of my HTML page is,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyChildApp', [])
        app.controller('MyChildController', function ($scope, $window) {
            $scope.data = $window.data;
            console.log($scope.data);
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyChildApp" ng-controller="MyChildController">
        Data: <span ng-bind="data.visitNumber"></span>
        <div ng-repeat="o in data">o.visitNumber</div>
        <div ng-repeat="o in data.data">{{o.visitNumber}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="o in data[0]">{{o.visitNumber}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside div i have been trying to display data some how but i am only getting this result,

```
Data:
o.visitNumber
o.visitNumber
o.visitNumber
o.visitNumber
o.visitNumber
```

I want to show that i have in console.log ,

```
"[{"areaNameEn":"malibu","buildingEnglishName":"national Hospital","visitNumber":"Visit_U_1"},
{"areaNameEn":"jordan","buildingEnglishName":"kateer Hospital"},"visitNumber":"Visit_U_2"]”
```

How can i display all this data in div or HTML with headers

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to interpolate with `{{}}`in the first one and are simply writing out text

Comment: I tried its not working

Answer (score 0):

I belive that your variable data is malformed. I think it should be

```
[{"areaNameEn":"malibu","buildingEnglishName":"national Hospital","visitNumber":"Visit_U_1"},
{"areaNameEn":"jordan","buildingEnglishName":"kateer Hospital","visitNumber":"Visit_U_2"}];
```

After that, the div should be like this

```
<div ng-app="MyChildApp" ng-controller="MyChildController">
    Data:
    <div ng-repeat="o in data">{{o.visitNumber}}</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps